# How to get unblocked Facebook page which has been blocked by Facebook for 30 days?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

My friend has his own Facebook Page, he mistakenly posted something which went against the community standards.  Now he has been blocked for 30 days.

How to unblock him?

Comment: He is lucky that he has been told that it's for 30 days.  I wasn't.  I had believed it was temporary and had started another page.  There is nothing you can do about it.  All you can do is ask for a review, which never changes the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your friend have violated Facebook Community Standards, and that's why he has been blocked. There is no way to get unblocked other than waiting. Don't do anything otherwise you might get blocked permanently.

The block is temporary, but it can't be lifted for any reason, so you'll need to wait until the block is finished.